# Use Laravel 5 Auth with custom table field name?

Tags: php, laravel-5

The error informatin is caused by the incorrect field in the database.

`QueryException in Connection.php line 620:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'`

The default field of auth is different from the database field, I want to use the database field in auth.

For example: the `email` field in my database call `user_email`, I want to change the database field into the auth field.

So, Are there any way to do this ?
Sorry for my poor English :)

THX;

Comment: Post your auth login code. The issue is there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get login with different database table column name in Laravel 5.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692506/how-to-get-login-with-different-database-table-column-name-in-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set whatever columns you like in the Auth::attemp method in your controller.

In your case bewlow construct should work

```
Auth::attempt(['user_email' => $email, 'password' => $password]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually we can override the getter/setter in an Eloquent model, but I haven't tried it on a User model.

```
class User extends Model{   
    .....
    // overriding getter & setter
    function getEmailAttribute() {
        return $this->attributes['user_email'];
    }

    function setEmailAttribute($value) {
        return $this->attributes['user_email']=$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.4 users,
some references I read to make it work,

https://medium.com/@simonhamp/why-and-how-to-override-laravel-s-built-in-auth-controller-methods-60f070897ac6

https://sujipthapa.co/blog/laravel-54-login-with-username-or-password

AuthenticatesUsers is trait which actually has login process.

If you are just going to change the name of column in user table from 'email' to 'your column',

```
public function username()
{
    return 'email';
}
```

We need to override(? I am actually not a good OOP developer), this method.

Like this

In loginController,

```
use AuthenticatesUsers {
  username as username;
}

public function username()
{
    return 'YOUR COLUMN';
}
```

Then it works like overriding username() method in trait.
Cheers !