# How to get login with different database table column name in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have to implement login functionality in Laravel 5.2. I have successfully done so using the official Laravel documentation except that I do not know how to authenticate the user using different database table column names, namely `st_username`and `st_password`.

I have searched the Internet for clues but to no avail.
I don't know which class I need to use (like, use Illuminate.......) for Auth.  If any one knows the answer, please let me know.

Here is my code:

Login View

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="contact-bg2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="booking">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div class="col-md-4 booking-form" style="margin: 0 33%;">
                <form method="post" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <h5>USERNAME</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="abcuser">
                    <h5>PASSWORD</h5>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="abcpass">

                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div></div>


@endsection
```

AuthController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
        $this->username = 'st_username';
        $this->password = 'st_password';
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
                    'name' => 'required|max:255',
                    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }
```

Route File

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

config/auth.php

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
//        'users' => [
//            'driver' => 'database',
//            'table' => 'users',
//        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I searched a lot how to customize **Laravel 5.2** authorisation form and this is what is working for me 100%.
Here is from bottom to top solution.

This solution is originally from here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/replacing-the-laravel-authentication-with-a-custom-authentication

but i had to make couple changes to make it work.

My web app is for the DJs so my custom column names are with 'dj_', for example name is dj_name

1. config/auth.php

   ```
   // change this
   'driver' => 'eloquent',
   // to this
   'driver' => 'custom',
   ```
2. in config/app.php add your custom provider to the list
       ...

   ```
   'providers' => [
       ...
       // add this on bottom of other providers
       App\Providers\CustomAuthProvider::class,
       ...
   ],
   ```
3. Create CustomAuthProvider.php inside folder app\Providers

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

   use App\Providers\CustomUserProvider;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class CustomAuthProvider extends ServiceProvider {

       /**
        * Bootstrap the application services.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function boot()
       {
           Auth::provider('custom', function($app, array $config) {
          // Return an instance of             Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...
           return new CustomUserProvider($app['custom.connection']);
           });
       }

       /**
        * Register the application services.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function register()
       {
           //
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create CustomUserProvider.php also inside folder app\Providers

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Providers;
   use App\User; use Carbon\Carbon;
   use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

   class CustomUserProvider implements UserProvider {

   /**
    * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
    *
    * @param  mixed $identifier
    * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
    */
   public function retrieveById($identifier)
   {
       // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.


       $qry = User::where('dj_id','=',$identifier);

       if($qry->count() >0)
       {
           $user = $qry->select('dj_id', 'dj_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')->first();

           $attributes = array(
               'id' => $user->dj_id,
               'dj_name' => $user->dj_name,
               'password' => $user->password,
               'email' => $user->email,
               'name' => $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name,
           );

           return $user;
       }
       return null;
   }

   /**
    * Retrieve a user by by their unique identifier and "remember me" token.
    *
    * @param  mixed $identifier
    * @param  string $token
    * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
    */
   public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
   {
       // TODO: Implement retrieveByToken() method.
       $qry = User::where('dj_id','=',$identifier)->where('remember_token','=',$token);

       if($qry->count() >0)
       {
           $user = $qry->select('dj_id', 'dj_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')->first();

           $attributes = array(
               'id' => $user->dj_id,
               'dj_name' => $user->dj_name,
               'password' => $user->password,
               'email' => $user->email,
               'name' => $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name,
           );

           return $user;
       }
       return null;



   }

   /**
    * Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
    * @param  string $token
    * @return void
    */
   public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
   {
       // TODO: Implement updateRememberToken() method.
       $user->setRememberToken($token);

       $user->save();

   }

   /**
    * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
    *
    * @param  array $credentials
    * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
    */
   public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
   {

       // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.
       $qry = User::where('email','=',$credentials['email']);

       if($qry->count() > 0)
       {
           $user = $qry->select('dj_id','dj_name','email','password')->first();


           return $user;
       }

       return null;


   }

   /**
    * Validate a user against the given credentials.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
    * @param  array $credentials
    * @return bool
    */
   public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
   {
       // TODO: Implement validateCredentials() method.
       // we'll assume if a user was retrieved, it's good

       // DIFFERENT THAN ORIGINAL ANSWER
       if($user->email == $credentials['email'] && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->getAuthPassword()))//$user->getAuthPassword() == md5($credentials['password'].\Config::get('constants.SALT')))
       {


           //$user->last_login_time = Carbon::now();
           $user->save();

           return true;
       }
       return false;


   }
   }
   ```
5. in App/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php change all
   'name' to 'dj_name' and add your custom fields if you have them...you can also change 'email' to your email column name
6. In Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User.php add

   ```
   protected $table = 'djs';
   protected $primaryKey  = 'dj_id';
   ```
7. In App/User.php change 'name' to 'dj_name' and add your custom fields.
   For changing 'password' column to your custom column name add

   ```
   public function getAuthPassword(){
       return $this->custom_password_column_name;
   }
   ```
8. Now backend is all done, so you only have to change layouts login.blade.php, register.blade.php, app.blade.php...here you only have to change 'name' to 'dj_name', email, or your custom fields...
   **!!! password field NEEDS to stay named password !!!**

Also, to make unique email validation change AuthController.php

```
'custom_email_field' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
to
'custom_email_field' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:custom_table_name',
```

Also, if you want to make custom created_at an updated_at fields change global variables in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php

```
const CREATED_AT = 'dj_created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'dj_updated_at';
```

Answer (score 3):

A custom Auth::attempt() doesn't work for me by changing the model in auth.php like this:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Person::class,
    ],
],
```

If I try to authenticate a Person via custom column names in Auth::attempt:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['persUsername' => $request->user, 'persPassword' => $request->pass])) {
    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

I get the same error:

> ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 112: Undefined index:
>   password

But I can authenticate a Person like this:

```
$person = Person
    ::where('persUsername', $request->user)
    ->where('persPassword', $request->pass)
    ->first();

if (! is_null($person)) {
    if ($person->persUsername === $request->user && $person->persPassword === $request->pass) {
        Auth::login($person, false);
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
}
```

But that's not the way it should be, I guess.

In the mentioned File (EloquentUserProvider.php), I see 'password' is hardcoded.

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
}

public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

So there is actually no way to use a custom column name for passwords the easy way?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy simply use the desired column names in  Auth::attempt()/method like so:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['st_username' =>$username,'st_password' => $password])) { 
    // Authentication passed... 
    return redirect()>intended('dashboard'); 
}
```

**Updated:**
If you also wish to change default authentication table which is `users` by default or change the model name or path `App\User` by default, you can find these settings in `config\auth.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

//'table' => 'users', 
'table' => 'new_tables_for_authentication',



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

//'model' => App\User::class,
'model' => App\Models\User::class,
```

Comment: I got this error on implementing your solution. `FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126: Class '\App\User' not found`

Comment: The error is definitely not from my solution. Where is your User model located or are you using another table for users?

Comment: I know that it's not from your solution. I'm just asking for help. Reason of error is location of `User.php` as it is in `app/Models/User.php`. So I changed it to `app/User.php`. But still problem arises as `ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 113: Undefined index: password`.

Comment: You need to change this in `config\auth.php`.  will update my answer

Comment: Canyou suggest me where to change in my `config\auth.php`? I'm posting that file

Comment: change  `'model' => App\User::class, to  'model' => App\Models\User::class,`