# Laravel 5.8 make:auth change field names not working

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.8

I tried to create a new Laravel app via `laravel new <app name>` and use the built-in Laravel authentication `make:auth`.

But I can't make it work when I change the `id` column is not in my table. 
The "ID" that I am using has a different column name, it is `StaffID`.

How could make it work? I don't see an `id` in my login code ( `make:auth` ).

Thank you.

Comment: so id StaffID still the primary key auto increment column? Try adding protected $primaryKey = 'StaffID '; to the User model directly in the class. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Provide your code sample to look at, otherwise its not possible to just guess and answer.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692506/how-to-get-login-with-different-database-table-column-name-in-laravel-5-2/35824963#35824963

Comment: I think you should create new column for `StaffID` and make it unique via `migration`. Change default ID `auto increment` column is not recommended.

Comment: Well I got it working now, @Petay87 comment is the key. I added `protected $primaryKey = 'StaffID'` and then boom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change the Primary Key associated with the Model

You have changed the name of the Primary Key on the database but Laravel by default makes an assumption that every table has a Primary Auto Incrementing Key of "id". There are many reasons for this, the most important being that it's standard practice to have this and it means you don't need to declare it on every model.

However, as you have changed your primary key from id to StaffID, Laravel needs to also be aware of this change to the Database. What you need to do is add the following to the users model directly within the Class:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'StaffID ';
```