# Laravel custom login username and password mapping

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I am upgrading a legacy application.
I am using Laravel 8 without ORM with DB first approach since the DB is already there.

I want to use

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->intended('shop');
    }
```

When I am configuring auth.php I saw inside the providers 'driver' => 'database' was commented. I want to use auth.php providers like following

```
'providers' => [
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
    //     'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    // ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'shop_users',
    ],
]
```

Is there any way I can map the user name password like following

```
'providers' => [
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
    //     'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    // ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'shop_users',
        'username' => 'email',       //Mapping auth username to table column
        'password' => 'password'     //Mapping auth password to table password
    ],
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692506/how-to-get-login-with-different-database-table-column-name-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: I have already gone through this question. What I am asking is cant we use the 'users' inside the providers to map usernames and passwords to custom columns.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this model call is extended Authenticatable

we need to add a new function inside app/Http/Auth/LoginController.php like below:

```
public function username(){ 
    return 'email'; // this string is column of shop_users table which we are going use for login 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yudiz, thanx for the solution. I am using laravel 8 and there is no such a directory as you mentioned app/Http/Auth.